# Indian National Travel to UK with Irish Visa (visitor, No BIVS)

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, london, ireland, dublin

I am an Indian Citizen traveling to Dublin.

My Irish visa does not have BIVS endorsement as it was issued in a center outside India.

I am flying into Dublin, staying there for a few days and then departing Dublin to London with a 12 hour stopover in London before my connection to Mumbai.

Can I pass border control in London using my Irish Visitor visa (no BIVS endorsed) for my 12 hour layover or do I need to get a UK Visitor Transit visa?

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/somewhere_else/yes.  Note the exceptions include "you’re travelling from the Republic of Ireland and it’s less than 3 months since you were last given permission, on the basis of holding a valid Irish biometric visa, to land or be in Ireland" so the only thing we don't know that could prevent you from qualifying is whether your visa is biometric.